# nginx reverse proxy selective caching

Tags: nginx

I have nginx running as a reverse proxy. Currently this is only providing centralized SSL termination and internet connectivity. I want to enable caching for static content.

The config for a virtual host on the proxy looks something like....

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name www.example.com;
   ...
   location / {
       include snippets/proxydefaults.conf;
       proxy_pass http://www.example.com.origin/;
   }
}
```

I am not confident that the caching on the origin servers is correctly setup, hence I only want to cache things which I know are static files. If I nest the caching config, do I need to repeat the config to apply the proxying, or is this inherited from the parent location....

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name www.example.com;
   ...
   location / {
       include snippets/proxydefaults.conf;
       proxy_pass http://www.example.com.origin/;
       location ~* \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|css)$ {
           proxy_cache default_cache;
           # do I need to explicitly add another proxy_pass directive here?
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request handlers are always explicitly set for a location. So proxy_pass won't be inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Nested locations are going bite you sooner or later; the non-trivial inheritance rules and having to copy-paste configs are both very likely causes of unnecessary problems.

Instead, you can define a variable (`set $dont_cache_this  1`), set it selectively to zero on "known static" content, and use it in conjunction with the [proxy_no_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_no_cache) directive.